# inspect getargvalues only grabs the current frame, how do I pass on a module that is a different Python file?

Tags: python, oop, dictionary, object, operating-system

I am new to using the inspect module, I have been able to use getmodule and getmembers but I want to now get the dictionary keys of a file called self.cat_feats in the init of a filename called some_file.py. The following code checks if the classes and modules in some_file.py contain the word 'inheritsomething':

```
    if file == "some_file.py":
        module = importlib.import_module(file.split('.')[0])
        module_members = inspect.getmembers(module)
        module_name = inspect.getmodule(module).__name__

        for member in module_members:
            if re.search('inheritsomething', str(member[1]), re.IGNORECASE):
                return True
```

I tried to use getargvalues in the following ways but it's wrong, I don't know how to pass in the some_file.py as I did for the other inspect functions.

```
frame = inspect.getargvalues(module_members)
frame = inspect.getargvalues(module)
frame = inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe())
```

I know currentframe doesn't work because it's getting the information of the file.py I am on, I want it for another Python file. How do I refer to that frame? some_file.py